# Lightning datatable column value misaligned

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable with column as type number

The row value in it is getting right aligned, while everything else is left aligned, I need to make it uniform.
[image: Family Details]

Here is what I tried --

```
    <div class="empFamilyTable">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="accountTable"
                     keyField="Id"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                     columns="{!v.FamilyDetailColumns}"
                     data="{!v.FamilyDetailData}"
                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"/>
    </div>
```

CSS--

```
 .THIS .empFamilyTable td {
   text-align: left !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number data types cell are aligned with css class **slds-grid_align-end**. It basically used to grow from the end of the horizontal axis. so if you override below style for **slds-grid_align-end** class then it will left align all number fields.

```
.THIS .slds-grid_align-end
{
    justify-content: left !important; 
}
```

Refer [SLDS guide](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) for this.

Answer (score 13):

In the attribute `FamilyDetailColumns` , try to use `cellAttributes` and apply `alignment` for the number column like this:

```
var columns = [{ label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', 
    cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }}
            // other column data
        ];
```

For more details refer to documentation below in section **Aligning Data in a Column**
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

Comment: This also works!!

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: worked like magic, the selected answer didn't justify the text columns like I wanted but this one did

Answer (score 0):

use slds-align_absolute-center

```
const columns = [
    {  
        label: 'Action',
        type: 'button', 
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Try me'
        },
        cellAttributes: {
            class: 'slds-align_absolute-center' // Center the button within the cell
        }
    }
];
```