# LWC Datatable percent data alignment off

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, formatting

So I've tried both of the solutions posted here:
[Lightning datatable column value misaligned](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271270/lightning-datatable-column-value-misaligned)
and neither of them are working for what I have.
[image: Visual of percentage cutoff]

The column above is the only sortable column in the datatable and is also the only one displaying a percent. The other columns are all text or integers. Below are the snippets from my .js and .css documents:

**percentMissedAssessmentQuestions.js** - column specs

```
    const columns = [
    {label: 'Question', fieldName: 'question', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Red Rating', fieldName: 'redRating', type: 'integer'},
    {label: 'Yellow Rating', fieldName: 'yellowRating', type: 'integer'},
    {label: 'Green Rating', fieldName:'greenRating', type:'integer'},
    {label: 'Percentage Missed', fieldName: 'percentageMissed', type: 'percent', sortable: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        step: '0.01',
        alignment: 'left'
    }
},
]
```

**percentMissedAssessmentQuestionsCSS.css**

```
 .THIS .slds-grid_align-end
{
    justify-content: left !important; 
    text-align: left !important;
}
.slds-grid
{
    justify-content: left !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

In addition, I inspected the page and found that the class containing the percentages is indeed .slds-grid_align-end, so I have no clue why my code isn't overriding it. It should also be noted that I have tried adding the .THIS prefix to both of the CSS classes to no avail.
The data in the table is being returned via JSON.
If anyone has any suggestions, they would be extremely appreciated. Thank you in advance,
Asmo

Comment: `alignment` is an attribute of `cellAttributes`, but you put it in `typeAttributes`, is it a typo? It should be `typeAttributes: { step: '0.01' }, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment should be in `cellAttributes` not `typeAttributes`.

```
  const columns = [
    {label: 'Question', fieldName: 'question', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Red Rating', fieldName: 'redRating', type: 'integer'},
    {label: 'Yellow Rating', fieldName: 'yellowRating', type: 'integer'},
    {label: 'Green Rating', fieldName:'greenRating', type:'integer'},
    {label: 'Percentage Missed', fieldName: 'percentageMissed', type: 'percent', sortable: true,
    cellAttributes: {
        alignment: 'left'
    },
    typeAttributes: {
        step: '0.01',
    }
},
]
```

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you so much! It would be something so small lol

Comment: If you see Shamina's answer in the link you provided, it already mentions this.

Comment: step: '0.01' is not working for me. Alignment works fine